# Basin of attraction of simple nonlinear coupled ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, systems-of-equations, basins-of-attraction

Consider ($\epsilon = 0.1$)

\begin{equation}\label{eq:general eq}
\begin{aligned}
\dot{x}_1(t) &= x_1(x_1-0.5)(x_1+0.5)+\epsilon x_2\\
\dot{x}_2(t) &= x_2(x_2-0.5)(x_2+0.5)+\epsilon x_1
\end{aligned} 
\end{equation}

Note that:

1. If consider the following ODE $$\dot{x}(t) = x(x-0.5)(x+0.5)+\epsilon x,$$ we have three equilibrium points: $\{-0.63,0,0.63\}$. $x=0$ is the stable equilibrium point. The basin of attraction of $x=0$ is $[-0.63,0.63]$.

---

Go back to the top coupled ODE. Let $$\begin{bmatrix}x_1(0) \\ x_2(0) \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0.63 \\ 0.63 \end{bmatrix}.$$

By doing so (same initial condition of $x_1$ and $x_2$), the top coupled ODE can be reduced to (since both are the same)$$\dot{x}(t) = x(x-0.5)(x+0.5)+\epsilon x,$$ with $x(0) = 0.63$. So $$\begin{bmatrix}x_1(0) \\ x_2(0) \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0.63 \\ 0.63 \end{bmatrix}.$$ is in the basin of attraction of the top coupled ODE.

---

However, based on the phase plotter, it shows that
$$\begin{bmatrix}x_1(0) \\ x_2(0) \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0.63 \\ 0.63 \end{bmatrix}$$ is not in the basin of attraction of the top coupled ODE.

($\epsilon = 0.1$)

http://kevbase.com/phase/

Can anyone please point out where I am wrong?

[image]

Comment: @Moo yes, just a coefficient or parameter. I set it to be 0.1.

Comment: @Moo In the picture of Wolfram Alpha, it looks like it is difficult to see if (0.63,0.63) is in the basin of attraction.

Comment: @Moo Yes! seems like (0.63,0.63) is not in the basin of attraction. So now my posted question makes sense. My question, in short, is why the reduced ODE cannot predict the basin of attraction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if the initial condition is on the line $x_1 = x_2$, the trajectory should always stay on that line, and be governed by the d.e. $\dot{x} = x (x - 0.5) (x + 0.5) + \epsilon x$.
However, the equilibria of that (with $\epsilon = 0.1$) are $0$ and $\pm 0.387298...$, not 
$\pm 0.63$.  $0.63$ is not in the basin of attraction of $0$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint.

A good stream plot can help a lot!

In red the equilibrium points for $\epsilon = 0.1$.

[image]

The corresponding MATHEMATICA script.

```
epsilon = 0.1;
str = StreamPlot[{x (x - 0.5) (x + 0.5) + epsilon y, 
    y (y - 0.5) (y + 0.5) + epsilon x}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
   MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y, vx, vy, n}, n], Mesh -> 55];
sols = Quiet[Solve[{x (x - 0.5) (x + 0.5) + epsilon y == 0, 
     y (y - 0.5) (y + 0.5) + epsilon x == 0}, {x, y}]];
equil = Table[Graphics[{Red, Disk[({x, y} /. sols[[k]]), 0.02]}], {k, 1, 
    Length[sols]}];
Show[str, equil]
```

Comment: How did you plot this?  by matlab or mathematica?  thanks!

Comment: @sleevechen With MATHEMATICA. The script  was attached to the plot as required.

Comment: Thanks so much! very helpful!

Comment: It is also interesting that streamplot reveals another invariant manifold for this system :)